# Migrating from build.gradle to build.gradle.kts having issue with some code snippets

Tags: android, kotlin, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl

```
Kotlin 1.4.10
AS 4.1
```

I have a `build.gradle (app)` that I am migrating to `build.gradle.kts`. The only 2 code snippets I haven't been able to change is the following.

Just wondering what the following should be in `build.gradle.kts`

```
productFlavors {
    project.android.buildTypes.all { buildType ->
        buildType.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.arguments =
            [
                    enableParallelEpoxyProcessing: "true"
            ]
    }

    variantFilter { variant ->
        def names = variant.flavors*.name

        if ((names.contains("sit") && variant.buildType.name == "release")
                || (names.contains("staging") && variant.buildType.name == "release")) {
            variant.ignore = true
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thinks it should be like this :

```
    productFlavors {
        project.android.buildTypes.forEach { buildType ->
            buildType.javaCompileOptions {
                annotationProcessorOptions {
                    argument("enableParallelEpoxyProcessing", "true")
                }
            }
        }

        variantFilter {
            val names = this.flavors.map { name }
            if ((names.contains("sit") && this.buildType.name == "release") ||
 (names.contains("staging") && this.buildType.name == "release")) {
                this.ignore = true
            }
        }
    }
```